# Custom NSView with outlets

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

Am new to Mac apps, and am writing one simple app which has a common layout for different sections of the app. Its basically an image with one or two buttons(titles keep varying) in all sections.

So I thought of creating a `CustomNSView` with one Image Well and two rounded buttons in a new Nib file and in a separate class file (MyCustomView, which is a subclass of NSView) it would load this Nib in `initWithframe` method. So now when ever I drag drop a custom view and set its class to `MyCustomView` I get the Image and two buttons instantly without any additional code. But now how would I control these buttons(outlets/actionms) in other View Controllers ? The same view will be used every where so I cannot set files owner in nib to the view controller ?

Is it right in doing so ? Is there any way to create a custom view which would delegate all button actions to which ever view controller its included in ?

Comment: wish I could set a bounty on this question. I really want to know if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom delegate. Though using that you can send messages from one object to another

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. I wouldn't create a CustomNSView, I would create a CustomViewController (with its xib file included).  On that CustomViewController, I would design the two buttons and setup CustomViewController.h like so.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate; // Create a delegate to send call back actions
-(IBAction)buttonOneFromCustomVCClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonTwoFromCustomVCClicked:(id)sender;
```

CustomViewController.m like so.

```
-(void)buttonOneFromCustomVCClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonOneFromCustomVCClicked:)]) {
        [self.delegate buttonOneFromCustomVCClicked:sender];
    }
}

-(void)buttonTwoFromCustomVCClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonTwoFromCustomVCClicked:)]) {
    [self.delegate buttonTwoFromCustomVCClicked:sender];
    }
}
```

In interface builder of your customViewController, link up both button's `SentAction` event to the two methods (they should be displayed in `file's owner`).

Then in your otherClass in which you want to load the generic custom view, instantiate the generic view controller like so.

```
#import "customViewController.h"

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    customViewController *newCustomViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"customViewController" bundle:nil];
    [newCustomViewController setDelegate:self];

    self.backGroundView = [newCustomViewController view]; // Assuming **backGroundView** is an image view on your background that will display the newly instantiated view
}

-(void)buttonOneFromCustomVCClicked:(id)sender {
    // Code for when button one is clicked
}

-(void)buttonTwoFromCustomVCClicked:(id)sender {
    // Code for when button two is clicked
}
```